# Open directory and create new file

Tags: ruby

I have this statement that creates nested directories:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils::mkdir_p ''+project_name+'/new_folder'
```

I want to add for example a new file called `README.md` inside `new_folder`. Is there a way to accomplish that with Ruby?

Comment: What is the `''+` for?

Comment: It grabs the user's input and creates it as the main file's name. ex: `project_name = gets.chomp`

Comment: I believe @sawa means the empty string '' is not necessary, Raymond.

Comment: anyway, it is better to use string interpolation instead of concatenation in cases like this:  `" #{project_name}/new_folder"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to do

```
path_name = "#{project_name}/new_folder"
FileUtils::mkdir_p path_name
FileUtils::touch("#{path_name}/README.md")
```

This will create an empty file named `README.md` inside your `project_name/new_folder` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
2.1.2 :015 > project_name = "foo"
 => "foo"
2.1.2 :016 > fld = FileUtils::mkdir_p "#{project_name}/new_folder"
 => ["foo/new_folder"]
2.1.2 :017 > FileUtils.touch "#{fld[0]}/README.md" if fld
 => ["foo/new_folder/README.md"]

[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/foo/new_folder]$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    3 retgoat  staff   102 17 май 17:44 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 119 retgoat  staff  4046 17 май 17:45 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 retgoat  staff     0 17 май 17:44 README.md
```

Please note I didn't test your code, but if it works for you, following example will create a file `README.md` inside `new_folder`

Answer (score 1):

For building filespecs, it's better to use the `File.join` method.  This is higher level, handles any extra or missing directory separators, and uses the right file separator for the OS on which it's running.

For example:

```
2.3.0 :006 > project_name = 'my_project'
 => "my_project"
2.3.0 :009 > filespec = File.join(project_name, 'new_folder', 'README.md')
 => "my_project/new_folder/README.md"
```

When the slashes are provided before and after 'new_folder', it still works:

```
2.3.0 :010 > filespec = File.join(project_name, '/new_folder/', 'README.md')
 => "my_project/new_folder/README.md"
```